# Can I make Orion Context Broker ignore additional fields in JSON payload in POST request

Tags: json, payload, fiware-orion

we want to transfer data from a Spark Core to the Context Broker using a regular POST request (v1/updateContext). We generate the following JSON payload:

```
{
"contextElements“:
    [
        {
            "type":"Producer“,
            "isPattern":"false“,
            "id":"1337“,
            "attributes“:
                [
                    {
                        "name":"currentPower“,
                        "type":"float“,
                        "value":“0"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"timestamp“,
                        "type":"int“,
                        "value":"2015-07-07T20:32:36.958Z“
                    }
                ]
        }
    ],
"updateAction":“UPDATE"
```

}

However, the firmware automatically adds additional fields (in addition to "contextElements" and "updateAction") to the JSON payload. The Context Broker responds with the error that there would be unknown fields. Can we make the Context Broker ignore those additional fields and only pick out the two that are required?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. This is the expected way of working, in the same way you cannot use more arguments than the allowed ones when calling a function in any conventional programming languages.

As workaround, you can use some intermediate proxy to filter out the JSON pieces that you firmware devices is generating and that doesn't conform with the NGSI API that Orion implements.